# How can I run a .robot file in AWS or a cloud to make triggers for a bot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, virtual-machine, robotframework

Im new with bots development and I have been working with **Robocorp** creating bots, and the **Robocorp Cloud** is too expensive for the tasks I want to develop.

So, first I would like to know if I can run my **.robot files** in **AWS**

Second, I would like to know if I can create triggers to start my robots there or in any other cloud or server, for example when ***myrobot@gmail.com*** recieves a mail, then my robot starts running without my intervention.

I would also like to know some options to develop triggers to start a **.robot file**

Can I store it in other clouds apart of AWS? Does AWS supports such files? Is there any other cloud I could storage my bots to run them? How can I do so? And is there any option for a **Virtual Machine** where I can run .robot files?

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can run robotframework anywhere where you can run python.  It can be virtual machine running any operating system that has new enough python, it can be aws ec2 instance, it can be your desktop, rasberry pi etc ..
2. If you need to ask "can I create a trigger", then the answer is probably no. Technically it is possible but what you need is not in the scope of vanilla robot framework. Easiest "solution" would be probably to run your "robot" in intervals and do a graceful stop in situation where there is no data to process.
3. How to implement a trigger ? You would still need something that polls your data/event source and once it gets information that like "there's 3 new emails in the inbox", you need to make something that triggers the event where the robot actually runs.  Another alternative is that you have a long running process that receives events from external sources and then passes that event to your robot. But once again, this is not straight forward "do this, then that" because things really depend on what you are trying to accomplish. I'd say as in #2, easiest way is to model your robot in, say every 10 minutes:

- start robot
- robot checks if any "unread" emails are in the inbox
- if not, stop
- if yes, continue with the normal flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rasjani.

Have you heard about WayScript? My idea of creating a trigger for a .robot file came from there, because with that program you can trigger your Python code via email as I said.

Also in Robocorp Cloud I can do a trigger via email but it is in Pro version which is really expensive for me.

So, is there no site or program where I can make such a trigger and not being too expensive? If not, well, thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: And as a last question, you mentioned Raspberri Pi, how can I run it via that way, I though I could do it via rcc but I could not.

Thanks a lot for your time